# How to disable the label with the input field of an HTML form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have tried JQuery and JavaScript to change the CSS for a label to cause it to grey out. But I have not succeeded.

the label comes beside a checkbox, and I'm able to disable the checkbox but not label beside it.

Label is created as follows:
Special

And I  want to change this label when someone clicks a radio button having id "idRadio".

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! What have you tried and what was the result? As you did in school... please show your work. :) It's part of the process of getting questions answered on SO. It's helpful to you because it forces you to investigate your own problem and think it through. It also proves to readers that you did your homework and made a reasonable attempt to answer your own question. Thirdly, it helps readers find and diagnose the problem resulting in a better answer for you and less time wasted for us.

Comment: Also you might get quick solution to your problem if you can replicate the same on jsfiddle, http://jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need jQuery nor Javascript to do what you want to achieve.

If your `<label>` tag is placed besides the `<input type=checkbox>` one, you can use a CSS selector:

```
/* gets the label that is immediately after a disabled input type=checkbox */
input[type=checkbox]:disabled+label {
  /* and changes its color to gray */
  color: gray;      
}
```

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    var cb = document.getElementById('cb');
    cb.disabled = !cb.disabled;
  });
});
```

```css
input[type=checkbox]:disabled+label {
  color: gray;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input id='cb' type='checkbox' disabled> <label for='cb'>My checkbox</label>
</div>
<div>
  <button>Toggle disabled</button>
</div>
```

---

**Updated**

Based on your comment, I've implemented a Javascript version to do what you want, but I don't recommend it at all. I'm only trying to help you here:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var radios = document.getElementsByName('idRadio');
  [].forEach.call(radios, function(radio, i) {
    radio.addEventListener('change', function() {
      var sp = document.getElementById('idSpecial');
      sp.disabled = (this.value === "0");
      sp.parentNode.removeChild(sp.nextSibling);
     
      var span = document.createElement('span');
      if (sp.disabled) span.style.color = 'gray';
      span.textContent = 'Special';
      
      sp.parentNode.insertBefore(span, sp.nextSibling);
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="idSpecial" name="Special">Special
<input type="radio" value="1" name="idRadio" checked>Enable</input>
<input type="radio" value="0" name="idRadio">Disable</input>
```

Comment: Label is created as follows:
<input type="checkbox" id="idSpecial" name="Special">Special</input>

And I  want to change this label when someone clicks a radio button having id "idRadio".

Comment: The `input` tag doesn't have a closing tag, so, you can't achieve what you want with CSS. Even with Javascript will be very ugly, but I'll edit my answer, so it works for your version. But if you can change your HTML code, I suggest you to do it.

Comment: I will change my HTML code as suggested. Thanks.